# How to get a list of the ids of elements that have a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know you can check if an element has a class with `element.classList.contains(class)`. However, that's not what I'm looking for - I want to be able to list all elements that have a certain class.

For example, if I have the following:

```
<div id="first" class="class1">...</div>
<div id="second" class="class1">...</div>
<div id="third">...</div>
```

What can I use so that I get an output of `#first` and `#second`? I'd like to avoid checking each and every one using the `.classList.contains()` method, as it is rather tedious and inefficient.

I'd prefer an answer using only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - thank you in advance.

Comment: In case you don't really need the ids but rather the elements themselves: `document.querySelectorAll('.class1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Array.prototype.map()

```
const ids = [...document.querySelectorAll(".class1")].map(el => el.id );
console.log(ids); // ["first", "second"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an Array of the `id` attribute-values:

```
// create an Array from the iterable NodeList returned by
// document.querySelectorAll():
Array.from(
  // retrieve all elements matching the selector:
  document.querySelectorAll('.class1')
// use Array.prototype.map() to return a new array
// based on the existing Array-elements/values:
).map(
  // using an Arrow function to return the id of
  // each node:
  (el)=>this.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem would be to use document.getElementsByClassName .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
const elementsWithClass1 = [...document.getElementsByClassName('class1')]
  .map(element => element.id);

console.log(elementsWithClass1);
```

```html
<div id="first" class="class1">...</div>
<div id="second" class="class1">...</div>
<div id="third">...</div>
```